How to organize an array list into a zig-zag when every other column has one less element
I'm making a program about packing circles and I need a zig-zag path between them, even though they are hexagonally packed. This means every other column has one less element sometimes. Here is a picture of how the path looks without zig-zag implemented:

And this is what my attempt is. For the first three rows it is working but for some reason it starts to get messy after that.

This is my code:
def zigzag_positions(cols, rows, stored_seed_positions, y_diff):
zigzag_positions = []
s = 0


for i in range(int(cols)):
    if i % 2 == 0:  # even cols
        for j in range(0 - s, int(rows), 1):
            index = i * int(rows) + j
            if index < len(stored_seed_positions):
                zigzag_positions.append(stored_seed_positions[index])
    else:  # odd cols
        for j in range(int(rows)-2, -1, -1):
            index = i * int(rows) + j
            if index < len(stored_seed_positions):
                zigzag_positions.append(stored_seed_positions[index])

        s += 1


return zigzag_positions

So basically every other set of coordinates that have the same x value need to be switched somehow. How would I do this? Here is an example array of the normal pathing:
[(102, 102), (102, 206), (102, 310), (102, 414), (102, 518), 
(193, 154), (193, 258), (193, 362), (193, 466), 
(285, 102), (285, 206), (285, 310), (285, 414), (285, 518), 
(376, 154), (376, 258), (376, 362), (376, 466), 
(468, 102), (468, 206), (468, 310), (468, 414), (468, 518), 
(559, 154), (559, 258), (559, 362), (559, 466)]

And here is the array I want:
[(102, 102), (102, 206), (102, 310), (102, 414), (102, 518), 
(193, 466), (193, 362), (193, 258), (193, 154),
(285, 102), (285, 206), (285, 310), (285, 414), (285, 518), 
(376, 466), (376, 362), (376, 258), (376, 154),
(468, 102), (468, 206), (468, 310), (468, 414), (468, 518), 
(559, 466), (559, 362), (559, 258), (559, 154)]


A typo in the 2nd row of your expected output : Are (193, 154) and (193, 362) swapped ?

Oh yeah sorry thats correct they should be swapped

IIUC, you want an alternating sorted :
from itertools import groupby, chain

out = list(
    chain.from_iterable(
        sorted(g, reverse=not i % 2)
        for i, (_, g) in enumerate(groupby(sorted(data), lambda t: t[0]))
    )
)

Output (made with matplotlib/shapely, see full code):

Used input :
# doesn't need to be sorted in any way

data = [
    (102, 102), (102, 206), (102, 310), (102, 414), (102, 518), 
    (193, 154), (193, 258), (193, 362), (193, 466), 
    (285, 102), (285, 206), (285, 310), (285, 414), (285, 518), 
    (376, 154), (376, 258), (376, 362), (376, 466), 
    (468, 102), (468, 206), (468, 310), (468, 414), (468, 518), 
    (559, 154), (559, 258), (559, 362), (559, 466)
]


for the correct output  sorted(g, reverse=not i % 2) need to be   sorted(g, reverse= i % 2)

Right but then, the zigzag's direction flips, see here. I'll leave it up to OP to chose the right one ;)

Yeah you right. Tbh I just checked input-output data that's why I mentioned

Thank you! Someone else gave me another solution though. For my robotics competition I'm making a program about planting seeds, but I started experimenting on what would be the best way to pack circles in a rectangle. Initially I thought that hexagonal was the best, but sometimes my program gives me aligned packing instead. If you want, could you run this code [https://pastebin.com/raw/SfvBqP2R] and see if it's the hexagonal packing is accurate? If it is, this would prove that aligned packing is sometimes ideal.

If I understand u clearly, you want to reverse for even rows. I tried to keep time complexity O(n) (it comes O(rows*cols) where rows*colms ≈ len(stored_seed_positions)) and I kept space complexity O(1).
Firstly, I checked if it is even rows or not. If it is then add rows to s. s is the index counter. If not I  switched list items by using a pointer.
def zigzag_positions(cols, rows, stored_seed_positions):
    
    s=0    
    for i in range(int(cols)):
        if i%2 !=0:
            right = s+3
            while s<right and right<len(stored_seed_positions):
                stored_seed_positions[s],stored_seed_positions[right] =stored_seed_positions[right],stored_seed_positions[s]
                s+=1
                right-=1
            s += (rows-1) // 2 if (rows-1) % 2 == 0 else (rows-1) // 2 + 1
        else:
            s+=rows
        
                
    return stored_seed_positions

Output is like :
[(102, 102), (102, 206), (102, 310), (102, 414), (102, 518), 
(193, 466), (193, 362), (193, 258), (193, 154),
(285, 102), (285, 206), (285, 310), (285, 414), (285, 518),
(376, 466), (376, 362), (376, 258), (376, 154),
(468, 102), (468, 206), (468, 310), (468, 414), (468, 518),
(559, 466), (559, 362), (559, 258), (559, 154)]


Thank you! But  if the rows and columns are changing in value, this only works when there are 6 columns and 5 rows (from the start). I fixed this by changing ' right = s+3 ' to ' right = s + (rows - 2) ' because it is dependent on the amount of rows.

@YasserMachkour yeah u right I missed that point.
